# Reusing sinkFile with Haskell Conduit

Tags: string, haskell, pipeline, conduit

I want to send a list of Photos to a sink to save them on the disk. Each Photo structure
contains a `content` field of type lazy ByteString.

Basically I want to do something like that:

`CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos`

I would like to reuse `CB.sinkFile` in my sink since, if I understand correctly, it does error management. Here is my attempt so far:

```
mkFilePath :: Photo -> FilePath
mkFilePath photo = last $ splitOn "/" (url photo)

sinkPhotos :: Sink Photo IO ()
sinkPhotos = do
    mphoto <- await
    case mphoto of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just photo -> do
          yield ct =$ CB.sinkFile fp
          sinkPhotos
          where fp = mkFilePath photo
                ct = BL.toStrict $ content photo
```

It fails with:

```
src/Screepy/Main.hs:30:23:
    No instance for (MonadResource IO)
      arising from a use of `CB.sinkFile'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MonadResource IO)
    In the second argument of `(=$)', namely `CB.sinkFile fp'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: yield ct =$ CB.sinkFile fp
    In the expression:
      do { yield ct =$ CB.sinkFile fp;
           sinkPhotos }
```

- How can I wrap `sinkFile` to work on a structure and not directly a `ByteString`?
- How can I create a `Source` from a `ByteString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm following all the questions you ask. I'll just address the type question: the error is only arising because of the signature you supplied. Doesn't this work?

```
sinkPhotos :: MonadResource m => Sink Photo m ()
sinkPhotos = do
    mphoto <- await
    case mphoto of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just photo -> do
          yield ct =$ CB.sinkFile fp
          sinkPhotos
          where fp = mkFilePath photo
                ct = BL.toStrict $ content photo
```

It is now just a question of finding the right place to use `runResourceT`, no? Querying `ghci` we see:

```
    >>> let photos = [] :: [Photo]

    >>> :t  CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos
    CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos :: MonadResource m => m ()

    >>> :t  runResourceT $ CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos
    runResourceT $ CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos
      :: (MonadThrow m, MonadBaseControl IO m, Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m) =>  m ()

    >>> :t  runResourceT $ CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos :: IO ()
    runResourceT $ CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos :: IO ()
```

So given a list of Photos, you can write

```
 main = runResourceT $ CL.sourceList photos $$ sinkPhotos
```

Edit: By the way, the type queries in ghci give clearer results if you use the type

```
 sinkPhotos :: Sink Photo (ResourceT IO) ()
```

though you may have reason to allow for other possibilities.

Comment: Is ```yield ct =$ CB.sinkFile fp``` correct at all?

Comment: I assumed a type `data Photo = Photo {url :: String; content :: L.ByteString}`. Then it's 'correct' in the sense that it typechecks. If you really want a lazy bytestring there, you should probably write instead: `CL.sourceList (L.toChunks ct) =$ sinkFile fp` to keep from concatenating texts. Since they're photos this may not be worth worrying about. You could also just make the photo `content` a bytestring `Source`. It would depend where they're coming from whether this was worth doing.

Comment: A strict bytestring `Source` is really the conduit version of a lazy bytestring.  The question would be whether you are stuck with `L.ByteString` somewhere anyway because the library you are using to get photo content on the page uses `L.ByteString`. If so, it probably doesn't matter where in your module you 'convert' to a conduit source.

Comment: I'm stuck with `L.ByteString` since I'm using `wreq` here and would prefer not to use `http-conduit` to avoid mixing two network libraries. How would you make the `content` a bytestring `Source`?

Comment: `CL.sourceList . L.toChunks :: Monad m => L.Text -> Source m S.Text`, which goes by way of a list (which is basically what a lazy bytestring is). I don't see a special combinator in the `conduit` modules I have around. There is also something like `L.foldrChunks (\t _ -> yield t) (return ()) :: Monad m =>  L.Text -> Source m S.Text` which folds directly on the lazy text, omitting use of an intervening list, not that that's likely to be important.

Comment: For some reason I was just testing lazy text not lazy bytestring. But it's the same: `foldrChunks` and `toChunks` are found in Data.ByteString.Lazy as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's compiling fine now. I'm surprised my wild guest `yield ct =$ CB.sinkFile fp` did actually worked, and that the type signature was the culprit. I guess I still need more training to decode ghc errors.